# Unable to run my program due to a 'WARN No appenders could be found for logger'

Tags: java, log4j, spring-batch, slf4j

I could not run/debug my program. Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/work/dev/workspaces/eclipse-kepler-websphere-workspace-WS1/smartcontestation-batch/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/work/dev/workspaces/eclipse-kepler-websphere-workspace-WS1/smartcontestation-project/shared-lib/ear/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/RSA/8.5/WASD8/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Comment: define a valid `log4j.xml` file in your project.

Comment: That's just a warning. It doesn't prevent your program from running.

Comment: indeed it prevent it from running. As I know I should define log4j.xml in my classpath. I define it in src/main/resources. Actually it was running before I did a clean/build in eclipse

Comment: When I run a simple main program I have a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution : I deleted some log files from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA\8.5\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01\logs' and did an eclipse clean. It re-worked after !